# Convert mongo Query to Java ArrayList<Bson>

Tags: java, mongodb, arraylist, bson

I need help in converting below mongo query to an ArrayList so that I can execute the query in spring boot app. Having tough time to convert it in java using Aggregate classe's match, group, etc. method.

private List aggregateInspectionWorkOrders(ArrayList operations) {
MongoCollection mongoCollection = db().getCollection(Constants.DB.MyTable, InspectionWorkOrder.class);
return mongoCollection.aggregate(operations).into(new ArrayList<>());
}

```
db.mytable.aggregate([
    {
$match: {
    $and: [
                    {
                        deleted: { $eq: false }
                    },
                    {
                        status: {
                                    $in: ['O', 'IP']
                        }
                    }
                ]
        }
    },
    {
    $group: {
            _id: {
                    sub: '$sub',
                    pre: '$pre'
                },
           location: { $addToSet:  { mile: '$mp'}}
         }
    },
    {
    $group: {
            _id: {
                    sub: '$_id.sub'
                },
            location: {
                $addToSet: {
                            pre: '$_id.pre',
                             from: {
                                $min: '$location.mp'
                            },
                            to: {
                                $max: '$location.mp'
                            }
                }
            }
           
         }
    },
    {
    $project: {
            _id: 0,
            sub: '$_id.sub',
            location: '$location'
            }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Found the easiest effort saving way to convert mongo query to Java compatible code using Mongo Compass. Follow below steps:
```
1. Inside Mongo Compass, go to Aggrgations tab.
2.  Click on "New Pipeline From Text"
3. Paste your array of match,group, project, etc. NOTE: proper spacing of each element is very important for mongo compass to read your array.
4. Click on Click New & import process is completed.
5. Now next to save button there is export button, try that and select your output code language. Export the code which can be now directly consumed.
```

Comment: 6. I converted it to Java which gave me response something like 
 Document{{sub=Del, location=[Document{{pre=ABC, from=1, to=2}}, Document{{pre=ADB, from=2, to=3}}]}}

7. ArrayList<Document> locnDocuments = mongoCollection.aggregate(query).into(new ArrayList<>());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return locDocuments.stream().map(document -> {
            try {
                return mapper.readValue(document.toJson(), StructuresLocationModel.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {...}
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());